# how to add search functionality to a txtbox 

Tags: asp.net

i want that while  writing some text in an asp.net textbox, a listview page should open which will show the related topics  containing that  text just below that txtbox .

i want to implement something as in stackoverflow title txtbox how it it showing related topics

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about how to call your "search" event as the text changes, or about how to write the actual search event?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will have to make an AJAX request to server after each keypress event in the text box and then display the result set dynamically. You will also need to write the server side method that takes the current input, carries out the search and returns the result.
jQuery would probably be helpful with this although there are alternatives such us ASP.NET AJAX.

Comment: i want to implement something as in stackoverflow title txtbox how it it showing related topics.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **AutoComplete** textbox from the AJAXControlToolkit. It has the exact functionality you are requesting, and the fetching of results is partially baked in by allowing you to wire up a service call to get the data.

Check out the following like which has an example of what you are needing.  Start typing in some text and the results will begin to display in a listbox fasion below the textbox.  Click on the 'AutoComplete Properties' link on the page to see how it works.

**AutoComplete Demonstration:**
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Then check out this video for more help:

**[How Do I:] Use the ASP.NET AJAX AutoComplete Control:**
http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-autocomplete-control

Comment: i want to implement something as in stackoverflow title txtbox how it it showing related topics from question page